# How else can I draw this apple?

Tags: image-processing

The following code is written by Luji.

```
uniqueColorQ[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := 
  0.01 > Max@Abs@Variance@Flatten[data[[y1 ;; y2, x1 ;; x2]], 1];

circleData[width_, height_, color_] := 
 Table[If[(j - width/2)^2 + (i - height/2)^2 <= (Quotient[
       Min[height, width], 2])^2, color, {1, 1, 1}], {i, height}, {j, 
   width}]

normalizeColor[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := 
 circleData[x2 - x1 + 1, y2 - y1 + 1, 
  Mean@Flatten[data[[y1 ;; y2, x1 ;; x2]], 1]]

blockMatrix[a11_, a12_, a21_, a22_] := 
 Join[Join[a11, a12, 2], Join[a21, a22, 2]] 
quadTreeArt[x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_] := 
 If[((x2 - x1) <= 1 || (y2 - y1) <= 1) || 
   uniqueColorQ[x1, x2, y1, y2], normalizeColor[x1, x2, y1, y2], 
  blockMatrix[
   quadTreeArt[x1, Quotient[x1 + x2, 2], y1, Quotient[y1 + y2, 2]], 
   quadTreeArt[Quotient[x1 + x2, 2] + 1, x2, y1, 
    Quotient[y1 + y2, 2]], 
   quadTreeArt[x1, Quotient[x1 + x2, 2], Quotient[y1 + y2, 2] + 1, 
    y2], quadTreeArt[Quotient[x1 + x2, 2] + 1, x2, 
    Quotient[y1 + y2, 2] + 1, y2]]]

image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxCYF.jpg"];
img = ImageResize[image, {500, 420}];
data = ImageData[img][[1 ;; 420, 80 ;; 500]];
Image@quadTreeArt[1, 400, 1, 400]
```

[image: apple]

What other ingenious methods can be used to achieve this effect?
[image: quadtree apple]

Comment: Code does not work for me on V12 Mac OS. "Image::imgarray: The specified argument {{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, <<391>>, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, <<399>>} should be an array of rank 2 or 3 with machine-sized numbers."

Comment: You need to manually replace the `image` in the question code with the image in the link.

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes just put the thing that calls `image = Import[...]` _before_ the code that uses it and it'll all work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not particularly efficient buy an easy to write recursion

```
ClearAll[splitMerge]
splitMerge[i_, maxSt_, minSize_, newImage_] :=
 ImageAssemble@Map[If[
     And[
      Max@ImageMeasurements[#, "StandardDeviation"] > maxSt,
      And @@ Thread[ImageDimensions[#] > minSize]
      ],
     splitMerge[ImagePartition[#, {Scaled[{1/2, 1/2}]}], maxSt, 
      minSize, newImage],
     newImage[#]
     ] &,
   i, {-1}]
```

Using these two functions to simplify the leaves

```
constantImage[i_] := 
 ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[i, 0], ImageMeasurements[i, "Mean"]]
diskImage[i_] := Block[
  {dims, mask},
  dims = ImageDimensions[i];
  mask = Image[DiskMatrix[Floor[Min[dims]/2], Reverse[dims]]];
  SetAlphaChannel[ImageMultiply[ColorConvert[
     mask,
     ImageColorSpace[i]
     ], ImageMeasurements[i, "Mean"]],
   mask
   ]
  ]
```

I get

```
splitMerge[ImageCrop[image, {400, 400}], .1, 20, constantImage]
splitMerge[ImageCrop[image, {400, 400}], .1, 10, diskImage]
```

[image: decompositions]

You can also try other types of matrices.